# Insert plain text just before last closing HTML tag

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in my web app. Once the user is done using the editor, they will choose some products from a selection list.

After that, they will click a preview button, at which time I need to programmatically insert some plain text immediately before the last closing HTML tag in the editor.  For example:

**Current Editor HTML:**

```
<p>The products you have chosen are: </p>
```

**After Inserting the plain text:**

```
<p>The products you have chosen are: product 1, product 2, product 3</p>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Try to use jquery

```
$( ":last-child" ).children().last().append("product 1 product 2 product 3");
```

Comment: Artur, thanks.  I edited my request for greater clarification.  The solution you provided does not suffice because the final tag in the editor content isn't known.  It will likely be a paragraph tag but even then, it's ID won't be known.  I need a way to figure out the last closing HTML tag and then insert some plain text immediately before it.

Also, if I just use +=, it will place the plain text after the existing content, creating an unnessary space.

Comment: i've tried and in your example would become <p>The products you have chosen are: product 1 product 2 product 3</p>

Comment: Please note that on Firefox (and sometimes on other browsers too) a bogus `<br>` may exist at the end of paragraph, so this solution will not work, because the text will be inserted after a line break.

Comment: but this code adds text adds the before the closing </p> not after it. But i've only tested on IE and on chrome so you might be correct

Answer (score 0):

var existingContent = CKEDITOR.instances.containerID.getData();

Gets the contents of whatever container you are using to hold the edit into a string var. Change 'containerID' to be the container's css ID. This will be 'editable' if you used the suggested code.

You can write the modified string back by using innerHTML, eg:
document.getElementById('editable').innerHTML=modifiedContent;

You may be thinking why not get the content by innerHTML - the answer is that innerHTML does not preserve formatting.

HTH

For an example of how this works, take a look at codebase/srcedit.php in Hyperframe 4. http://sf.net/projects/hyperframe.